# Add route prefix to all actions in controller using one attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Here is my controller

```
public class SpecializationsController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult Action1()
    {
        //body
    }

    public ActionResult Action2()
    {
        //body
    }
```

Default url for Action1 is of course `/Specialization/Action1`. I want to add prefix to all Actions in my controller to make my ulr like `/prefix/Specialization/Action1`.

I tried to add `[RoutePrefix("prefix")]` to my controller but it doesn't work. I would like to avoid adding `[Route]` attribute for each action in my controller. So how can I add this prefix?

Comment: Why do you want a prefix? I ask because I have an answer but I want to make sure it will make sense for your case.

Comment: I have an AdminController which can redirect me to FacultiesController or SpecializationController, I want to add an Admin prefix to all actions of those controllers just to make it "cleaner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create [Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas):

> Areas are an ASP.NET MVC feature used to organize related functionality into a group as a separate namespace (for routing) and folder structure (for views). Using areas creates a hierarchy for the purpose of routing by adding another route parameter

I know you may think this is an overkill for simply having a "prefix" but the reason I suggest this approach is because if you have the need to add a "prefix", chances are you have the need to separate the views, models etc. as well.

Comment: That's it, Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a route to your route collections instead of using route attributes

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Route",
            "prefix/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Specializations", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: This will work, but it affects *all* controllers. To affect *only* the `SpecializationsController`, the `url` argument should be `"prefix/specializations/{action}"`.